# Single result for user_id sorted by multiple dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table containing `positions`
This table is as follows:

```
user_id | current | started_at  | finished_at
2       |  false  | 10-07-2016  | 02-08-2016
1       |  false  | 19-07-2016  | 27-07-2016
1       |  true   | 29-07-2016  | null
3       |  true   | 20-07-2016  | null
3       |  false  | 01-07-2016  | 18-07-2016
```

I'm sorting this table using a case to use either the `started_at` or `finished_at` date depending on whether `current` is true or false

```
SELECT *
FROM positions
ORDER BY
  CASE
      WHEN current = true 
          THEN started_at
      ELSE finished_at
  END
 DESC
```

This works fine as expect but now I want to extract only the first row for each `user_id`

So in my example data i'd like to only have the following returned.

```
user_id | current | started_at  | finished_at
2       |  false  | 10-07-2016  | 02-08-2016
1       |  true   | 29-07-2016  | null
3       |  true   | 20-07-2016  | null
```

I was thinking this could be done with a `GROUP BY` but I can't get it to work without error or maybe I need a sub query, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is that "only the first row" equals to `WHERE current = true` ?

Comment: sorry that's a mistake, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent opportunity to use a window function. You can use the window function to create a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT  user_id, current, started_at, finished_at, 
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS row_number
    FROM positions
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN current = true 
       THEN started_at ELSE finished_at END DESC
```

This will give you your original table with a new column "row_number" that comes from the window function. You partition by user_id because you want to get the row_number by user. Use the ORDER clause you provided. To get the full answer just use this statement as a subquery, use the WHERE clause to only choose row_number = 1, and pull all the fields you need. Window functions cannot be used in the WHERE clause, which is why you need the subquery.

```
SELECT  user_id, current, started_at, finished_at
FROM
(
SELECT  user_id, current, started_at, finished_at, 
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS row_number
FROM positions
ORDER BY CASE WHEN current = true 
   THEN started_at ELSE finished_at END DESC
) pos
WHERE row_number= 1
```

Comment: Also - if you are new to Window functions here is some good documentation from PostgreSQL: [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i like the approach. unfortunately it doesn't give me the expected results. The results are not sorted by the date columns. It orders by user_id http://pastebin.com/r5LkYXGC

Comment: I see what you mean. I edited the answer to pull the sort outside the partition and used the row_number() function instead of rank(). Rank would give you duplicate "1" values in the case you had the exact same dates for the same user_id. I don't know if your full dataset would have that or not - but better safe.

Comment: Thanks @mattperry it should never have the same dates for a user_id but there's only app level enforcement of that, so like you say better to be safe. Works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you made a mistake in your example, since your desired result shows the *second* row for `user_id` 1.

You can easily achieve what you want with the non-standard PostgreSQL `DISTINCT ON` feature:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM positions
    ORDER BY
       CASE
          WHEN current = true
          THEN started_at
          ELSE finished_at
       END
    DESC) q;
```

This will remove all but the first row for each `user_id`.

Comment: It's the first row sorted by the date the expected result in my example is correct. Unfortunately your answer errors "SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions"

Comment: Thanks for your help @laurenz-albe unfortunately the resulting dataset is not sorted by the date used in the case as only the inner select is sorted. I do now have a working version from Matt. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Well, it would be trivial to wrap it with another query that performs a sort, but the solution with a window function is probably better.